# Connection could not be created with Liquibase on to MySQL -> Communications link failure

Tags: mysql, docker-compose, database-migration, liquibase, mysql-connector

For some reason I can't run my liquibase against my database, I am not sure where I am going wrong here. The error I am getting is about driver:

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Connection could not be created to jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/patshala?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true with driver com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver.  Communications link failure
backend-liquibase-1  | 
backend-liquibase-1  | The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
backend-liquibase-1  |   - Caused by: Connection refused
```

This is my docker compose file, all I am doing is a `docker-compose up`.

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_DATABASE: patshala
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  liquibase:
    image: liquibase/liquibase:latest
    command: [
      "--url=jdbc:mysql://mysql:3306/patshala?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true",
      "--username=root",
      "--password=root",
      "--changeLogFile=/changelog/db.changelog.xml",
      "update"
    ]
    volumes:
      - ./db:/liquibase/changelog
      - ./mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar:/liquibase/lib/mysql-connector-j-8.1.0.jar
    depends_on:
      - mysql

networks:
  app-network:
    driver: bridge
```

My docker compose file is in the folder ./backend and my driver is at the folder ./backend, so it definitely can read the drive jar file.
[image]